# Display total characters count on vim statusline

Tags: vim, statusline

I want to add a function to my statusline by which I can display the total characters count of the current file.
`:help statusline` showed me that `F` referes to `Full path to the file in the buffer`, and through a bit searching I got to know how I can display the output of a shell command. So i currently have these in `.vimrc`:

```
set statusline+=%#lite#\ %o/%{DisplayTotalChars()}\

function! DisplayTotalChars()
    let current_file = expand("%:F")
    let total_chars = system('wc -c ' . current_file)
    return total_chars
endfunction
```

This is what it displays now in the status line, whereas I only need the characters count not the file path to be displayed:

> 36/29488 /home/nino/scripts/gfp.py^@

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set statusline+=%#lite#\ %o/%{DisplayTotalChars()}\
```

That part is correct, minus the `\` at the end which serves no purpose.

```
let current_file = expand("%:F")
```

That part is incorrect because the `F` you found under `:help 'statusline'` means something when used directly in the value of `&statusline` but it is meaningless in `:help expand()`, where you are supposed to use `:help filename-modifiers`. The correct line would be:

```
let current_file = expand("%:p")
```

And a working function:

```
function! DisplayTotalChars()
    let current_file = expand("%:p")
    let total_chars = system('wc -c ' . current_file)
    return total_chars
endfunction
```

But your status line is potentially refreshed several times per second so calling an external program each time seems expensive.

Instead, you should scrap your whole function and use `:help wordcount()` directly:

```
set statusline+=%#lite#\ %o/%{wordcount().bytes}
```

which doesn't care about filenames or calling external programs.

Answer (score 5):

As both `system()` and `wordcount()` being called repeatedly do a lot of unnecessary work and burn extra CPU time that may even result in slowing down your machine (especially while working on a huge file), you're strongly advised to use `line2byte()` instead:

```
set statusline=%o/%{line2byte(line('$')+1)-1}
```

Or even better, press <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-g</kbd> whenever you really want to get this info and keep your statusline clean.

Comment: `wordcount().bytes` was doing just fine, but since the method you mentioned is more efficient, I replaced it with `line2byte(line('$')+1)-1`. Thanks.

Comment: g Ctrl-g ... that's it for me